# Using binary operator "--" for vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have my own Class Vector and I'd like to create an operator-- to delete last element in array. But in my implementation i got an error:

> binary "--": Vector does not define this operator or a conversion to a
>   type acceptable to the predefined operator.

How do i declare it correctly?

```
class Vector {
private:
    int *vect;
    int size;
public:
    void operator--();
}
void Vector::operator--() {
    int *tmp = vect;
    size--;
    vect = new int(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) vect[i] = tmp[i];
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

Comment: How did _you_ declare it?

Comment: @tkausl  void operator--();

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Comment: As to your implementation, all you need to do is simply subtract 1 from the `size` variable.  You don't need to reallocate and recopy anything.  Isn't it `size` that determines the number of elements?  And I agree with the previous comment -- this should be a `pop_back()` function, not an overloaded `--`.

Comment: @FilipVondrášek done

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought of it, just can't check because of compilation error.

Comment: @pookeeshtron [Please read the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just got a task to impliment it as --.
Anyway thanks, I alreayd found the solution.

Comment: Even if you fix the declaration, the implemention is still wrong. `new int(size)` needs to be `new int[size]` instead. And the code doesn't account for the possibility of `size` being 0, or the possibility of `new` throwing an exception. And really, there is no need to reallocate `vect` at all, decrementing `size` is sufficient by itself, if you simply add a `capacity` member to the class so the allocated size can be different than the populated size.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I should have declared it like this:

```
void operator--(int);
```

And implemented like this:

```
void Vector::operator--(int) {
    if (size>1) size--;
    else std::cout << "Only one element in vector.\n";
}
```

this (int) helps the compiler to differ prefix and postfix increments or decrements.

An example:

```
struct A {
    void operator --(int) { std::cout << "Postfix\n"; }
    void operator --() { std::cout << "Prefix\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a--;
    --a;
}
```

Thanks to @PaulMcKenzie for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: And if some one want to call u = v--; ?

Comment: @TungLeThanh we should return Vector then instead of void.